# Inclusion of .futureValue method in scala.concurrent.Future?

Tags: scala, akka, alpakka

I am working through a tutorial on getting data from an S3 bucket via [this tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/s3.html) (the full test code [can be found here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v2.0.2/s3/src/test/scala/docs/scaladsl/S3SourceSpec.scala#L33-L40)).

When I use the code

```
val s3names: Source[Option[(Source[ByteString, NotUsed], ObjectMetadata)], NotUsed] =
S3.download(bucket, bucketKey)
val Some((data: Source[ByteString, _], metadata)) = s3names.runWith(Sink.head).futureValue
```

I get

```
[error] ...../src/main/scala/streams/package.scala:33:82: value futureValue is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[Option[(akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed], akka.stream.alpakka.s3.ObjectMetadata)]]
[error]   val Some((data: Source[ByteString, _], metadata)) = s3names.runWith(Sink.head).futureValue
```

After too much exploration, I find that a futureValue method exists in the ScalaFutures class of the scalatest package but I do not see ScalaFutures in the imports of the relevant test code (it is available elsewhere).

While I may eventually have a question on the details of using Alpakka S3, I am really confused about where this .futureValue method is coming from and why it apparently works in the Alpakka test package.

Using Akka 2.6.12, akka-stream-alpakka-s3 2.0.2 and Scala 2.13.4.

Comment: This spec extends `S3WireMockBase' and  'S3ClientIntegrationSpec` traits - type class goes in somehere from them, most likely from 'S3ClientIntegrationSpec'

Comment: Got it -- S3ClientIntegrationSpec extends ScalaFutures, so you are right.